# Make Jersey response from entity of another Jersey response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, multipart, jersey-client

Sorry for clumsy title of question, but it's absolutely absurd situation.
I'm using Jersey client to receive data from third-party server. On my side I'm await multipart/mixed data, and most of the times it works. But sometimes server response with application/octet-stream data, and the entity of this response is... multipart/mixed packet that I'm waiting for.

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="XXXXXXX"

--XXXXXXX
Content-Type: image/gif
datadatadata
```

So I need to create Jersey Client response from this entity.
I tried to do it with ReaderInterceptor

```
public class MMSLargeAttachmentHandlerFix implements ReaderInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> m = context.getHeaders();
        fixISAndHeaders(context);
        return context.proceed();
    }

    private void fixISAndHeaders(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(context.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
        context.getHeaders().putSingle("Content-Type", br.readLine());
        br.readLine();
        context.setInputStream(new ReaderInputStream(br, "ISO-8859-1"));
    }

}
```

But when I try to read entity I get exception with cause "missing start boundary". So it seems that I miss something in my approach.